# Getting document associated to maximum field value in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working with documents having three fields: deviceId (integer), timestamp (date) and channel (string). My final goal is to find, for each deviceId, the most recent document, and then aggregating these documents by channel.

Right now, I've successfully grabbed the latest timestamps by deviceId, but I'm struggling to capturing the channel field associated with the maximum timestamp of each deviceId.
I'm thinking that I'm probably not solving this problem the right way. Is there any other way, or am I close to the solution?

The incomplete request:

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "deviceId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "deviceId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "time": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The example I'm working with:

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties": {
      "deviceId" : { "type" : "integer" },
      "timestamp": {"type" : "date"},
      "channel": {"type": "text"}
    }
  }
}

POST test/_doc/1
{
  "deviceId" : 456,
  "timestamp" : "2022-03-24T11:00:00.000Z",
  "channel" : "A"
}

POST test/_doc/2
{
  "deviceId" : 456,
  "timestamp" : "2022-03-24T12:00:00.000Z",
  "channel" : "B"
}

POST test/_doc/3
{
  "deviceId" : 123,
  "timestamp" : "2022-03-24T11:00:00.000Z",
  "channel" : "C"
}

POST test/_doc/4
{
  "deviceId" : 123,
  "timestamp" : "2022-03-24T12:00:00.000Z",
  "channel" : "D"
}

POST test/_doc/5
{
  "deviceId" : 123,
  "timestamp" : "2022-03-24T13:00:00.000Z",
  "channel" : "E"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The channel needs to be a keyword in order to do aggs on it. There are no support for aggs on text fields

Comment: Does aggregating by channel and then finding the maximum timestamp work as a solution?

Comment: I actually don't wan't to aggregate on channels straight away. In the given example, channels A, C, D should not be considered. If the aggregation is done first on channels, all channels will be there in the result.